# Database in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

This is the code in oracle, but not working in SQL Server. Can someone please rewrite the code for Microsoft SQL Server 2012?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "BI_NEWACCOUNT" 
  before insert on "NEWACCOUNT"               
  for each row  
begin   
    select "NEWACCOUNT_SEQ".nextval into :NEW.ACCOUNTNO from dual; 
END;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is *not* a code translation service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself** and then if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working**.

Comment: i had some problems.. but then correcting on every step was difficult

Comment: ok more specifically ...
what shall i write in place of "before" , "for each row" in the code??
and when i run it "NEWACCOUNT_SEQ" , this part says the multi-part identifier could not be bound ??

Comment: @SohamBasu, then you should start looking for that error instead of asking someone to write the query for you.

Comment: [Official MSDN **documentation** on `CREATE TRIGGER` for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support Sequences like Oracle.  Forget the trigger and just set the NEWACCOUNT_SEQ as an IDENTITY column.

Comment: SQL absolutely has sequences. But of course the syntax is vastly different than Oracle's. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: Identity column will provide what he needs. Yes SQL 2012 provides sequences.

Comment: From SQL Server 2012 onwards we can create a sequence